# Jenkins Scheduling build run even when it is logged out or system shut down?

Tags: jenkins, triggers, automation, scheduled-tasks

I have created a TestNG project in Jenkins and trying to schedule that job to run and send the result to email. My build is running periodically when I scheduled and sending the results to email. Now my question is

1. Will Jenkins run the build which we scheduled even if we log out of Jenkins?
2. Will Jenkins run the build which we scheduled even if we shut down our laptop?

If not what is the process to get rid of it. I have a build, that should run everyday morning 8 am before I came to office; my laptop will be in shutdown or sleep mode. Jenkins will trigger the scheduled job even if my laptop is shut down or if I log out of Jenkins?

I want to know how to make my scheduled build run.

Comment: Is Jenkins deployed on your own laptop?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 3):

First of all common practice is to deploy Jenkins to a server which is always up or at least at the time of scheduled time. 
If Jenkins is deployed on your own laptop then it will run build if Jenkins service is running.

> 1. Will Jenkins run the build which we scheduled even if we log out of Jenkins?

Yes, It will run as logging out of Jenkins won't stop Jenkins service.

> 2. Will Jenkins run the build which we scheduled even if we shut down our laptop?

No, It won't run as Jenkins service won't be running while the laptop is shut down or in sleep mode.

To check Jenkins service status on windows using the command line run following command

```
sc queryex "jenkins"
```

You can also check service status using `services.msc`

1. Open run using `Ctrl+R`
2. type `services.msc` and press enter
3. Find `jenkins` service and double-click to see details

[image]

To check status on Linux run

```
service jenkins status
```

Comment: Jenkins is installed on my own laptop which i use for my office purpose also.
How to deploy Jenkins to a server? can you explain me step by step procedure?

Comment: When you install Jenkins it automatically installs and starts the service.

Comment: Is it installed on Windows or Linux?

Comment: Why people use windows as server?

Answer (score 0):

If Jenkins run on your laptop and you will shut down your lap top Jenkins process will not run meaning your scheduled build will not run.

The Jenkins (service Windows / daemon Linux) need to run. Logging out will not affect on your Jenkins.

Comment: How to get service windows on my laptop? and after getting service windows what are steps to take to run my scheduled builds?

Answer (score 0):

> If not what is the process to get rid of it. I have a build, that should run everyday morning 8 am before I came to office; my laptop will be in shutdown or sleep mode. Jenkins will trigger the scheduled job even if my laptop is shut down or if I log out of Jenkins?

1. Not possible if the laptop is shutdown.
2. But if it is in sleep you can [schedule a task from windows task scheduler](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-automated-task-using-task-scheduler-windows-10), (the task itself can be to run some dummy bat file) with the settings to make the system wake up at scheduled time so that the jenkins can run the build.
   I have tried this for some of my use-case and it works fine.